# Change text in link element using CSS

Tags: html, css

Apologies, I'm new and learning (slowly!)

I'm trying to get StyleBot to change the text in a link on web page I am viewing, but don't have access to edit.

I'd like to change the text from "Awaiting Approval" to "Work in Progress".

Here's the HTML the page is generating:

```html
<li><a href="/Approval/Search.aspx?jobStatus=STATUS/SUBMITTED">
          Awaiting Approval
          <span>
            (13)
          </span></a></li>
```

I've tried a bunch of things with conditional selectors, but must be missing something.  Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You probably can use a pseudo element and font-size : https://jsfiddle.net/zvk98bpm/  `a {
  font-size:0; 
  text-decoration:none;
}
a:before {
  content:'Work in Progress ';
}
a span , a:before {
  font-size:1rem; 
}`

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you try to do ?

```css
a {
  font-size: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:before {
  content: 'Work in Progress ';
}

a span,
a:before {
  font-size: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="/Approval/Search.aspx?jobStatus=STATUS/SUBMITTED">
      Awaiting Approval
      <span>
        (13)
      </span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yes, thanks you for your help. 